# .htaccess private folder jwplayer

Tags: apache, .htaccess, jwplayer

I have a player.php script that loads a video into jwplayer, this is located in my httpdocs folder.

This works fine, when the video is in the same folder. If I move the video from httpdocs, to say the private folder on the same level as httpdocs, the video won't load.

So to clarify:

```
/httpdocs/player.php loading -> /httpdocs/video.mp4 is OK
/httpdocs/player.php loading -> /private/video.mp4 is erroring (Error loading media: File could not be played)
```

I'm not sure why it's doing this, I have read that php scripts should be able to access the files in the /private folder?

Alternatively if I can add a folder such as /httpdocs/video/ to place the video in, but make it so the video can't be accessed via http, that would work. It's essentially so no one can download the video directly.

Thanks in advance,

Dave

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JW6, set the player's "type" variable to "mp4". If you are using JW5, set the player's "provider" variable to "video".

Comment: Thanks for helping Ethan, here's what I have now (same error):

http://jsfiddle.net/JPNj2/

Comment: You only have the JS here, no html or jw player loaded it seems?

Comment: Yeh, the jw player is being loaded ok, so is jQuery. There is 1 div that is loading the player, this too is working, it's just the video isn't loading...

Comment: Can you provide an actual link to where this is running? These files do not exist:

flashplayer: "/var/www/vhosts/test.com/subdomains/media/private/jwplayer.flash.swf",
    file: "/var/www/vhosts/test.com/subdomains/media/private/video/video.mp4", //PMH